# INSERT values from one table to another with the same ID NUMBERS

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in the same database. I would like to pass some information from one table to the other.

In the first table "products", I have products_id, products_length, products_width and  products_height and I would like to pass all the information from that table to a second one called "product".

The second table "product" has the following columns product_id, lenght, width and height.

In both tables the products are the same ones and they have the same ID NUMBER.

I just need help on how to INSERT the values from "products" to "product".

Comment: Do you want to do this using SQL alone or will you be using another language  (PHP, etc)?

Comment: Using SQL alone.  I just need to pass the length, width and height from table products to table product that its empty.  Thanks

Comment: See my answer below along with some other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just asking for this?

```
INSERT INTO
    product (product_id, length, width, height)
SELECT
    products_id
    ,products_length
    ,products_width
    ,products_height
FROM
    products
```

If you're just trying to migrate data, can you just copy the table? Or rename it and the columns?

Comment: YES I am trying to migrate data from oscommerce to opencart.   Both tables already have information.  I am just interested in migrating those colums from one table to the other.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE product LIKE products;
INSERT INTO product SELECT * FROM products;
```

Comment: +1 assuming he doesn't want to just duplicate the columns indicated.

Comment: I cannot create table product, because it is already CREATED and has more colums on it and If I CREATE a new table I would erase all the info inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You should really think of improving the scheme you have. You have a lot of duplicated information which will cause performance and maintenance hell. The table products should not store information for a given product but rather should only have a foreign key to a product in the second table product.

Comment: How do you know what he's trying to do with his schema?

Comment: `In both tables the products are the same ones and they have the same ID NUMBER.` even only this sentence tells me there is something wrong with his schema

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (product_id, lenght, width, height)
  SELECT products_id, products_lenght, products_width, products_height 
  FROM products
  WHERE products_id=3
```

You can remove `WHERE` clause if you want to insert all records of products.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i'd suggest you improve your DB schema - your duplicating some information.

But to answer you could use:

```
INSERT INTO product (product_id, length, width, height) 
SELECT products_id ,products_length ,products_width ,products_height FROM products
```

Another option would be to duplicate the table, rename it and then rename your columns?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

and Use :

```
INSERT INTO product (product_id, length, width, height) 
SELECT products_id ,products_length ,products_width ,products_height 
FROM products
```

Before copying the data, also verify the schema for both tables.